# Want to draw same graph by changing scaling of the axis

Tags: graphs

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,bindingoffset=0.2in,left=0.7in,right=0.7in,top=0.7in,bottom=0.7in,footskip=.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage[centertags]{amsmath}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{newlfont}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,intersections}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[thick,latex-latex] (-2,0) -- (5,0)node[right]{$x$};
    \draw[thick,latex-latex] (0,-2) -- (0,5)node[above]{$y$};
    \node at (-0.3,-0.3) {O};
    \foreach \x in {-1,1,2,3,4}{
        \node[fill,circle,inner sep=1.5pt,label=below:$\x$] at (\x,0) {};
        \node[fill,circle,inner sep=1.5pt,label=left:$\x$] at (0,\x) {};
    }
    \draw[thick,stealth-stealth, shorten >= -2cm, shorten <= -2cm,name path =b ] (0,4) -- (4,0)
    node[pos=0.65,above,sloped] {$ $};
    \foreach \x/\y/\name in {0/4/B,4/0/A}{
        \node[fill,circle,inner sep=2.5pt,label={[inner sep=0pt]above right:\name($\x, \y$)}] at (\x,\y) {};
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Go through the above codes, is the codes for the graph of x+y=4
 I want to draw a graph of x+y=100. 
How can i make it possible?